# How to make this page transition fluid?

Tags: jquery

I want to create a fade out, fade in effect between page transitions.

I use this code to fade in:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  $(document.body).fadeIn("fast");
});
```

And this code to fade out:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  $(document.body).fadeOut("fast");
});
```

The code does work but the transition does not execute fluidly. How can I make the fading more fluid, so that it looks like a natural motion?

Comment: fluently? Are you saying "fluid" or "fluent"?  I'm assuming fluid, ie the fade is choppy and *not* smooth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various examples on how to do this, short of posting CSS and JS code to give you an eample I am going to point you to a good reference here:

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/

Difference between what you did and the above example, is they stop the default link action, create a transition, once the transition completes, they resume the default (ie load a link).

In your case you fire on page unload, which will get cut off as it is simply the moment of the page transitioning, which you don't have control over.

Answer (score 0):

HTML animation varies greatly from machine to machine and browser to browser. The best you can do is slow it down a bit.